Is there a merge-view in eclipse that is similar to intelliJ?
I would like to have a merge-view in eclipse that is split into 3 parts like intelliJ does it. For example: left is my local state, right are the changes from server and in the center is the resulting file.
Is there a way to show such a merge-view in eclipse?

In the Compare editor when doing a three-way compare, there is the button Show Ancestor Pane in the toolbar in the upper right.

Is it possible to put the ancestor pane next to the other two panes? Because at the top it doesn't really help a lot

I'm not aware of an option to show the ancestor pane next to the other two panes. If you think that this adds value and is not just what you are used to, make a pull request.
